# error in matplotlib library in python while using csv2rec

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am working in Ipython, trying to load a csv file.

```
from matplotlib import *
data=matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec('helix.csv',delimiter='\t')
```

Here is the error message

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/mnt/hgfs/docs/python/<ipython console> in <module>()
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mlab.pyc in csv2rec(fname, comments, skiprows, checkrows, delimiter, converterd, names, missing, missingd, use_mrecords)
   2125 
   2126     # reset the reader and start over
-> 2127     fh.seek(0)
   2128     reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=delimiter)
   2129     process_skiprows(reader)      
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

Does someone already run on this error? I tried to re-install everything, I am working with Python2.7 and I have Matplotlib v0.99.3, Numpy v1.5.1, Ipython0.10.1

Comment: I still did not find the answer to this problem, but to read my csv files I am using another command line:    'from numpy import *'    'ld=numpy.genfromtxt('file.csv',names=True,dtype=None,delimiter='\t')'

Comment: there must be something wrong with the file, you should provide it for somebody to help.

Comment: I tried with a simple file I created (2 columns, 2 lines with numbers) and it didn't work either, so I'm not sure the problem is in the file.

Comment: ok, please provide the code to create that simple file.

Comment: I didn't use any code, I went to Excel, named the first line "markers", the 3 other lines: line1, line2 and line3; for the columns, I named them snp1, snp2, snp3, and for line1 I put A,A,A line2 was A,B,A and line3 was B,B,B. Then I just saved the file as file.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this file:

```
snp1,snp2,snp3
A,A,A
A,B,A
B,B,B
```

and here is the result:

```
In [3]: csv2rec('helix.csv')
Out[3]: 
rec.array([('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B')], 
      dtype=[('snp1', '|S1'), ('snp2', '|S1'), ('snp3', '|S1')])
```

I have matplotlib 1.0.1, so you might try updating it, I do not have access to older matplotlib for testing.

Comment: so you just upgraded matplotlib?